# using try-catch, how can i recall the try again if the input was wrong?

Tags: java

am building bookstore system
one of the methods will ask the user to enter the book name then description then the book's code.
My question is, how can i recall the try if there was "InputMismatchException".
I mean the catch will print to the secreen "Wrong Input!" but i want to prompt the user to input again

here is my code

```
public void add(){
    try{
    System.out.println("Enter the book code :");
    int c = s.nextInt();
    try{
        System.out.println("Eneter the book quantity");
        int q = s.nextInt();

        try{
            System.out.println("Eneter the book description");
            String d = s.next();

            try{
                System.out.println("Eneter the book cost price");
                double cp = s.nextDouble();

                try{
                    System.out.println("Eneter the book selling price");
                    double sp = s.nextDouble();

                    try{
                        System.out.println("Enter status: [a for available - u for unvailable]");
                        String input = s.next();
                        if(input.equals("a")) {
                            System.out.println("available: ");
                        }
                        else if (input.equals("u")) {
                            System.out.println("unavailable ");
                        } 
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
                        }

                        try{
                            System.out.println("enter the discount on the item \"if exsist\"");
                            double dis = s.nextDouble();
                        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                            System.out.println("Wrong Input");

                        }
                    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                        System.out.println("Wrong input");
                    }
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){

                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("WRONT INPUT!!");
            }
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("WRONG INPUT!!");
        }
    } catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Wrong input. NUMBERS only!!");
    }
} catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("You have to enter a NUMBER only");

}
```

Comment: Why are these nested this way?

Comment: Each piece that you are prompting should be a method of its own.  Inside the method, you handle looping until you get a valid input (or an exit flag).  When the method returns, it will return the valid input (which may have taken several tries) or the flag (perhaps a return of `null`) that signals to end this input.

Comment: HOLY COW A GUACAMOLE

Comment: You shouldn't have that many tries in your code!

Comment: UI politeness hint: Using exclamation marks in messages is like shouting at your user. Even more when using two of them. Even more than more in combination with all uppercase. It might be a personal opinon but I don't like to be shouted at by unintelligent machines, a.k.a. computers (too).

Comment: Jared, i dont want to use loop if it is possible to do it with try-catch.

Comment: @mazin You need a loop.  `try-catch` will not loop.  If you want to repeat something multiple times (which is what you're doing, since you're asking the user to input multiple times until he gets it right), that's what loops are for, so why do you not want to use a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a loop of some sort, either `while` or `do-while`.

```
boolean invalidInput;
do {
    invalidInput = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the book quantity");
        int q = s.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");  // this is more polite
        invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        s.nextLine();
    }
} while (invalidInput);
```

You don't need to nest all the `try/catch` blocks if you do this; perform one input until it's valid, then do the next one, etc.

As one commenter said, it would be best to put each input in a method.  If you do this, you don't need a `boolean`:

```
private int getBookQuantity() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the book quantity");
            int q = s.nextInt();
            return q;           
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");  
            s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

which is an "infinite loop" that exits when the `return` statement returns a valid value.  Even better might be to write just one method for inputting `int` values (and others for `double`, `String`):

```
 private int getInteger(String whatToEnter) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the " + whatToEnter);
            int q = s.nextInt();
            return q;           
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer.");  
            s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot that `nextLine()` is needed after an invalid input; this throws out the invalid integer and everything else on the line so that it won't cause another exception repeatedly.

Comment: all the solutions will keep on looping "infinite loop" if the input is incorrect.

Comment: @mazin I forgot that `nextLine()` is needed.  Please see my edit.